# Jquery webview app is superslow, how do I speed it up?

Tags: android, jquery, performance, android-webview, android-manifest

I am using JQuery in my android webview, and the app is extremely slow, takes about 10-15 seconds to navigate across. Is there a way I can speed it up? I have tried every thread and almost every trick in the book, is there anything I am missing? And yes I already added hardwareaccelerated in manifest, still no luck!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       // getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setInitialScale(1);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
      //  webview.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
       webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
       // webview.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        //http://www.inpixelitrust.fr/demos/restaurant_picker/
        //file:///android_asset/index.html
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

       /* webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
         {
           // update the progressBar
           MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
         }
        });*/
        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }

    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            synchronized (SPLASH_LOCK) {
                SPLASH_LOCK.notifyAll();
            }
          }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share more details about what exactly is slow? What is the content that you are loading?

Once thing that is very wrong in your code is calling `loadUrl` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. Please don't do this, just return `true`.

What is `SPLASH_LOCK` used for? Where do you wait on it?

Comment: splash lock is used for splash timing, its not affecting the speed thing.I tried and tested the same. Can you explain how to replace loadurl with code? I don't understand. Also, i am using jquery contents, like html files,css, jquery etc, and by slowness I mean it takes about 10-15 seconds to nvigate unlike 2-5 seconds in normal apps. I know webview is a little slow and it's common, but was wondering if I could somehow speed it up.

Comment: You should just remove the loadUrl call from shouldOverrideUrlLoading. shouldOverrideUrlLoading only needs to return true :)  The slowness is likely to be something to do with the content you are loading, can you share it?

Comment: it doesn't make much of a difference, but I uploaded the code on server and seems to be working fine now, thanks